# error: too many many input arguments matlab

Tags: sql, matlab, input, arguments

I am trying to execute a Sql query in matlab. The sql uses 'select' command for selecting a particular row using a columnname which matches a value that is stored in variable given in the following code.
When I execute this , I get an error : Error using ==> database.exec Too many input arguments.

```
q=value;%computed value. 
conn1=database('Dbname','',''); 
fna=exec(conn1,'select * from table1 where ImageName="',q,'"');
fna=fetch(fna); fda=fna.data;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing four input arguments, the last three ones must be concatitated to one sql command.

```
sqlquery=['select * from table1 where ImageName="',q,'"'];
fna=exec(conn1,sqlquery);
```

Comment: :Further i am storing the contents of fda in a cell. When i try to print the contents present in the cell , there is another error :      C = fda.';                          sprintf('%d%d%d'C{1,1},C{2,1},C{3,1})                                                        Error :Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.

Answer (score 0):

in the matlab manual it says that exec has the following syntax:

```
curs = exec(conn,sqlquery)
curs = exec(conn,sqlquery,qTimeOut)
```

You have four parameters in the exec functions, that's what the error means!